# How to get through all breakpoints?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have placed multiple breakpoints in a project, and in some instances while debugging, I feel the need to get through all the breakpoints to see the result immediately, then restart the debugging, to pinpoint what the code is exactly doing.

My question is: how do I do that? Is there a shortcut to press? Other alternatives?

Thanks a lot..

Comment: "Stop debugging"? (Then re-attach the debugger as required.) I only know how to *remove* all breakpoints ..

Comment: "On the Debug menu, click Disable All Breakpoints." in Visual Studio? - Depends on what editor you're using I suppose. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb211czx(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Stop debugging and re-attach breakpoints will take a long time :).     @jwinn, I only see the option to disable individual breakpoint. How do I do that for all of them?

Comment: If using VS, in breakpoints window I usually do a CTRL+A, and select the button "Disable All Breakpoints", like jwinn said

Comment: I was having trouble finding Disable All Breakpoints, but I got it. Thanks a lot, jwinn and ryrich.

Answer (score 0):

You can use F10 to Step Over, F11 to Step Into, F5 to run the code per breakpoint.

F11 is much usable because of through debugging, 
Even though you only place one breakpoint it goes step by step in each method.

Answer (score -1):

F11  is step by step
F5 is jump to next break point 
Good Luck

Comment: Actually, `F5` is 'continue'.  He wants to know how to skip breakpoints.